# (node: 8432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: ionic3

I am trying to run on android device. this error will shown.Someone please help me.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 29s <br>
46 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 43 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        E:\Ionic3 Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Sourav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
No target specified, deploying to device 'Q37300630MS08002131'.

none
Skipping build...
Built the following apk(s):
        E:\Ionic3 Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Using apk: E:\Ionic3 Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Package name: io.ionic.starter
(node:8432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: C:\Users\Sourav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
adb: failed to install E:\Ionic3 Projects\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.ionic.starter signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (E:\Ionic3 Projects\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
(node:8432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8432) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Package io.ionic.starter signatures do not match the previously installed version

Uninstall the app from your device and build it again with CLI

Comment: @SouravGolui you can accept the answer by clicking the green tick